# What does it mean for one geometrical axiom to be considered _equivalent_ to another geometrical axiom?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

What does it mean for one geometrical axiom to be considered *equivalent* to another geometrical axiom?

For example consider Playfair`s axiom:

*In a plane, given a line and a point not on it, at most one line parallel to the given line can be drawn through the point.*

This is always described as being equivalent to Euclid's parallel postulate (the 5th postulate) which states:

*If a line segment intersects two straight lines forming two interior angles on the same side that sum to less than two right angles, then the two lines, if extended indefinitely, meet on that side on which the angles sum to less than two right angles.*

However in Euclidean geometry two points are required to define a line. Therefore I would argue Playfair's axiom is not logically equivalent to Euclid's fifth postulate since it posits the existence of lines through a single point. Playfair's axiom is often characterized as a more streamlined version of Euclid's postulate but I suspect this is because it tacitly uses ideas that are not present in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Playfair's axiom does not posit a line "containing" a single point. There is an assumption that it makes sense to say that a point is (or is not) on a given line, and also whether a given line passes through (or not) a given point. Given a point, choose another point and the two points identify a line which passes through them both.

Comment: For the line which is said to be "parallel", Playfair's axiom relinquishes the power of specifying the second point to the line. The mind let the line "choose" the location of second point, whereas in Euclidean geometry  the location of the second point is deliberate because it precedes the construction of the line. 
Playfair imbued the line with the power to specify the location of the second point and this opened the door to non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Intentionality is a beautiful thing.

Comment: I think you are reading this wrong. Through a point there may be many lines: they either exist or they do not - but there are points on the original line ... . Playfair as you state it simply says that at most one of these possible lines is parallel to the original - it doesn't even assume the existence of any line through the point: that remains to be demonstrated. (There ia also a question about what makes two lines the same line.)

Comment: Since it is an axiom a demonstration is not necessary.

Comment: Have you ever read Euclid? As well as the axioms and propositions there are lots of definitions.

Comment: I haven't read all of it. There are also many  versions of it. According to this writer Euclid probably left the concept of a "straight line" undefined. http://intellectualmathematics.com/blog/euclids-stupid-definition-of-a-straight-line-is-not-euclids/
He argues the definition , “A straight line is a line which lies evenly with the points on itself,” is dumb and was added to the text centuries later.

Comment: In my opinion this is a good version: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/bookI.html
Straight lines are always shown with two points as they should be according to Euclid's postulates. eg. https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/post5.html

Answer (score 5):

First, there is an implicit presumption that one is working with a background set of axioms that I'll denote $\mathcal S$. In your question, $\mathcal S$ is the set of axioms of what I believe is called "neutral geometry", which means Euclid's axioms (suitably formalized) *without* the fifth postulate. In particular, $\mathcal S$ includes the axiom that two points define a line, and a bunch more axioms.

Consider now two further axioms under consideration, which I'll denote $A_1$ and $A_2$. In your question $A_1$ is Euclid's fifth postulate and $A_2$ is Playfair's axiom.

To say that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are logically equivalent (under the implicit presumption that $\mathcal S$ holds), means:
$$\mathcal S \implies (A_1 \iff A_2)
$$
This is tautologically equivalent to the following, which is how I would expect the equivalence of the $5^{\text{th}}$ postulate and Playfair's axiom to be actually proved:
$$\bigl((\mathcal S \quad\text{and}\quad A_1) \implies A_2 \bigr) \quad\text{and}\quad \bigl( (\mathcal S \quad\text{and}\quad A_2) \implies A_1 \bigr)
$$

Comment: How would a proof that they are not equivalent read?

Comment: Hard to say, since they truly are equivalent in this sense.

Comment: How can that be since it obviously incorporates ideas that are not present in  Euclid postulates. Maybe they are present in the so called "neutral geometry".

Comment: Euclid incorporated ideas that are not present in Euclid's postulates. Neutral geometry is nothing but the outcome of two thousand years of filling holes in Euclid's postulates, to clarify the underlying unstated assumptions in Euclid's own arguments.

Comment: By the way, the phrase "suitably formalized" in my answer refers to this neutral geometry.

Comment: An assumption behind neutral geometry is that the meaning of the first four postulates  exists independently of 5th postulate. However, I am not aware of Euclid ever saying the 5th postulate was optional. I think this bias crept into the study of Euclidean geometry in course of  trying (and failing) to prove the 5th postulate from the first four.

Comment: "Bias" is not really an adequate descriptor of the situation. Instead, geometers from Euclid's time onward worked hard to solve the following mathematical question: Does the 5th postulate follow from the other postulates? Or is it instead independent of the other postulates? Hard work on this problem over two millenia produced improvements of Euclid's own work, as well as an eventual solution to that mathematical question.

Comment: Some early influential commentators on the Elements had the reasoned opinion -- but it was still just an opinion -- that the 5th postulate needed proving. The opinion spread like a meme until it eventually became a normal mathematical preoccupation. As a consequence it became natural to make sense of Euclid's postulates as a collection of independent parts.