# Why can't we prove Euclid's fifth postulate from propositions 27 and 29?

Tags: geometry, axiomatic-geometry

Proposition 29 state that:

> A straight line falling on two parallel straight lines, makes the alternate angles equal to one another [...]

And the fifth postulate was used:

> [...] therefore two straight lines which intersect are parallel to the same straight line, which is impossible.

Would a better postulate be, (distinct) lines parallel to the same line are parallel, and thus [black and yellow are parallel, but they intersect, which is absurd, as it contradicts with the definition of parallel](https://www.c82.net/euclid/book1/#prop29)?

Comment: Searching questions in Math SE with this tag "axiomatic geometry" can help you to get pertinent information, e.g. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4170910/305862, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4511178/305862

Comment: You cannot prove the postulate from Prop 27. It is independent of it and holds in hyperbolic geometry, see [Elements I.27, Guide](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI27.html). Prop 29 does not hold in hyperbolic geometry and hence is equivalent to the postulate, see [Elements I.29, Guide](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI29.html). You can derive the postulate from Prop 29 using Prop 13.

Comment: Yes, it is, see [Elements I.30, Guide](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI30.html). A number of equivalents with proofs are listed in [Williams's notes](https://mathed.byu.edu/~williams/Classes/362F2006/Notes/Equivalents%20to%20the%20Euclidean%20Parallel%20Postulate.pdf). I do not know how to tell which one is "better". The most popular equivalent now is ["Playfair's" axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair%27s_axiom#History), which actually goes back to Proclus.

Comment: So @Conifold does that also imply that the transitivity cannot be proved otherwise (without the fifth postulate or a substitute)?

Comment: That's part of what "equivalent" means. If it could be proved without then the parallel postulate itself could be derived from the rest, which it cannot be.

Comment: @NumberBasher: Your proposed "transitivity of parallel-ness" axiom is #10 in the list of Equivalent Properties in Wikipedia's ["Parallel Postulate" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate#Equivalent_properties).